# Python Access to BaseRequestHandler

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, serversocket, requesthandler

My code basically needs to start up a simple chat server with a client.  Where the server and the client can talk back and forth to each other.  I've gotten everything to be implemented correctly, but I can't figure out how to shut down the server whenever I'm done.  (I know it's `ss.shutdown()`).

I'm wanting to end right now based on a keyword shared between the two (something like `"bye"`), but I don't know if I can somehow send a message to my `SocketServer` from `BaseRequestHandler` to `shutdown()` whenever it receives the message.

Eventually, my goal is to incorporate `Tkinter` to make a GUI, but I wanted to get everything else to work first, and this is my first time dealing with sockets in Python.

```
from sys import argv, stderr
from threading import Thread
import socket
import SocketServer
import threading
import sys

class ThreadedRecv(Thread):
    def __init__(self,socket):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.__socket = socket
        self.__message = ''
        self.__done = False
    def recv(self):
        while self.__message.strip() != "bye" and not self.getStatus():
            self.__message = self.__socket.recv(4096)
            print 'received',self.__message
        self.setStatus(True)

    def run(self):
        self.recv()

    def setStatus(self,status):
        self.__done = status

    def getStatus(self):
        return self.__done

class ThreadedSend(Thread):
    def __init__(self,socket):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.__socket = socket
        self.__message = ''
        self.__done = False
    def send(self):
        while self.__message != "bye" and not self.getStatus():
            self.__message = raw_input()
            self.__socket.send(self.__message)
        self.setStatus(True)

    def run(self):
        self.send()

    def setStatus(self,status):
        self.__done = status

    def getStatus(self):
        return self.__done



class HostException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.value)

class EchoServer(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def setup(self):
        print self.client_address, 'is connected!'
        self.request.send('Hello ' + str(self.client_address) + '\n')
        self.__done = False
    def handle(self):

        sender = ThreadedSend(self.request)
        recver = ThreadedRecv(self.request)
        sender.start()
        recver.start()
        while 1:
            if recver.getStatus():
                sender.setStatus(True)
                break
            if sender.getStatus():
                recver.setStatus(True)
                break         

    def finish(self):
        print self.client_address, 'disconnected'
        self.request.send('bye client %s\n' % str(self.client_address))
        self.setDone(True)

    def setDone(self,done):
        self.__done = done

    def getDone(self):
        return self.__done



def setup(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    server = False
    defaultPort,defaultHost = 2358,"localhost"
    hosts = []
    port = defaultPort
    serverNames = ["TRUE","SERVER","S","YES"]
    arg1 = arg1.upper()
    arg2 = arg2.upper()
    arg3 = arg3.upper()
    if arg1 in serverNames or arg2 in serverNames or arg3 in serverNames:
    server = True
    try:
        port = int(arg1)
        if arg2 != '':
            hosts.append(arg2)
    except ValueError:
        if arg1 != '':
            hosts.append(arg1)
        try:
            port = int(arg2)
            if arg3 != '':
                hosts.append(arg3)
        except ValueError:
            if arg2 != '':
                hosts.append(arg2)
            try:
                port = int(arg3)
            except ValueError:
                if arg3 != '':
                    hosts.append(arg3)
                port = defaultPort

    for sn in serverNames:
        if sn in hosts:
            hosts.remove(sn)

    try:
        if len(hosts) != 1:
            raise HostException("Either more than one or no host "+ \
                                "declared.  Setting host to localhost.")
    except HostException as error:
        print error.value, "Setting hosts to default"
        return (server,defaultHost,port)

    return (server,hosts[0].lower(),port)

def main():
    bufsize = 4096
    while len(argv[1:4]) < 3:
        argv.append('')
    settings = setup(*argv[1:4])
    connections = (settings[1],settings[2])
    print connections
    if not settings[0]:
        try:
            mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,\
                                     socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        except socket.error, msg:
            stderr.write("[ERROR] %s\n" % msg[1])
            sys.exit(1)
        try:
            mySocket.connect(connections)
        except socket.error, msg:
            stderr.write("[ERROR] %s\n" % msg[1])
            sys.exit(2)

        message = ""
        print "Enter a message to send to the server. "+\
              "Enter \"bye\" to quit."
        sender = ThreadedSend(mySocket)
        recver = ThreadedRecv(mySocket)
        sender.start()
        recver.start()
        while 1:
            if sender.getStatus():
                recver.setStatus(True)
                break
            if recver.getStatus():
                sender.setStatus(True)
                break    

    else:
        xserverhandler = EchoServer
        serversocket = SocketServer.ThreadedTCPServer(\
            connections,xserverhandler)
        server_thread = Thread(target = serversocket.serve_forever)
        server_thread.setDaemon(True)
        server_thread.start()
        # I would like to shut down this server whenever 
        # I get done talking to it.
        """while 1:
            if xserverhandler.getDone():
                print 'This is now true!'
                serversocket.shutdown()
                break"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Yeah, I know setup() is a terrible function right now with the try's and catches, but it works for now, so I was going to fix it later.

My question is basically: How can I get the server to actually end based on a message that it receives?  If possible, is there a way to access the Request Handler after it's started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please fix your code so it works, and include some way to use it. You need to add

```
class ThreadedTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    pass
```

since SocketServer doesn't actually include that class (at least not in my version of 2.6 nor 2.7). Instead, it's an example from the [SocketServer definition](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html).

Please include an example of how to start/use the code. In this case to start the server you need to do:

```
ss.py SERVER localhost 8001
```

and the client as

```
ss.py localhost 8001
```

If you do that then you can't do server_thread.setDaemon(True) because there are no other threads running, which means the server will exit immediately.

Once that's done the solution is to add a call (or two) to self.server.shutdown() insdie of your EchoServer.handle method, like:

```
    while 1:
        if recver.getStatus():
            sender.setStatus(True)
            self.server.shutdown()
            break
```

However, I can't get that to work, and I think it's because I inherited things wrong, or guessed wrong in what you did.

What you should do is search for someone else who has done a chat server in Python. Using Google I found http://www.slideshare.net/didip/socket-programming-in-python and there are certainly others.

Also, if you are going to mix GUI and threaded programming then you should look into examples based on that. There are a number of hits when I searched for "tkinter chat". Also, you might want to look into twisted, which has solved a lot of these problems already.

What problems? Well, for example, you likely want an SO_REUSEADDR socket option.

Answer (score 1):

Request handler object is created for each new request. So you have to store "done" flag in server, not handler. Something like the following:

```
class EchoServer(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    ...
    def setDone(self):
        self.server.setDone() # or even better directly self.server.shutdown()
```